# Unknown error HERE maps AbstractMarker error in mapjs-core

Tags: javascript, here-api

HERE map error
[image]

I've contacted the HERE dev support team and they could not give me an answer as to what would cause this error. I am hoping someone else has run across this error. We have a code base that has not been changed in a month and everything was working fine. Then one day this error started happening and prevents the Map from even loading.

The top error in the image is the one that is reporting from the HERE JS SDK and I believe to be the first domino in my other errors.

Comment: Maybe the way to build the application changed though? It sounds like the code initializing the map could be executed too early. Are we sure it is executed once the map container element is ready in the DOM tree? Is the script with the `new H.Map` call in a script tag at the end of the body tag, or in a handler triggered once the DOM is ready?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: I've been trying to fix these problems. At first the solution you provided seemed to work since the error from maps-js was not longer being thrown, but not that I have fixed the WDS error the mapsjs-core issue persists.

Would you have any other insight. I even added the map SDKs locally to make extra sure none of the others are being loaded before the tothers

Answer (score 0):

Please download new available lite SDK android version 4.x. Please refer the new methods and optional parameters at the following reference :

```
developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.AbstractMarker.html
```